# Why is my html rendering messed up in Qt Assistant?

Tags: html, qt, python-sphinx, qt-assistant

I have written a documentation using Sphinx, and as the software is written in Qt, I have tried the qthelp Sphinx output engine. The Sphinx installation is brand new and nothing was customized, and I tried with the simple Sphinx project from the documentation "First Steps with Sphinx".

The resulting html displays nicely in firefox, with the default Sphinx skin.

Then I compile this to .qhc using qcollectiongenerator.exe (under windows) and load it with Qt Assistant.

The document contents are there, but the rendering is ugly. For instance, the whole document has a dark blue background, whereas firefox only applies this color to the title bars.

Is the Qt HTML renderer fully incompliant? Is there a way to tell Sphinx to generate Qt friendly HTML styling?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Is the Qt HTML renderer fully compliant?"_ Almost certainly not. I'm not aware of a _browser_ which is fully compliant, never mind a software component like Qt's.

Comment: Qt Assistant uses the built-in webkit to display the help pages. It applies certain default styling that is up to you to override by providing your own style sheets.

Comment: But the compiled html does contains its stylesheets. You can't have them automatically embedded in the qch?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having quite the same problems like you and I'm very unsatisfied with the produced output.

After some investigations I found out, that our Qt-5.5 Assistant works properly, whereas the Qt-5.10.0 Assistant was broken.

Opening the About-Dialog revealed the important difference between these two versions.

[image: Qt 5.5 with Qt WebKit]

[image: Qt 5.10.0 with QTextBrowser]

The Qt 5.10.0 Assistant was compiled with `QTextBrowser` in order to display the contents of the help file. It seems, that `QTextBrowser` lacks the ability to display CSS content, which destroys the layout of the help file.